# CMake: Invoke custom command as part of make install

Tags: cmake, pip

I'm working on a CMake project in which I want to install a generated Python module as part of `make install`. I have tried the following, where the CMake variables are hopefully self explanatory:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${PYTHON_MODULE}.egg-info"
  COMMAND pip install "${PYTHON_BIN_DIR}"
  DEPENDS "${PYTHON_MODULE_SO}"
)

add_custom_target(python_egg DEPENDS "${PYTHON_MODULE}.egg-info")

install(TARGETS python_egg)
```

However, this results in `install TARGETS given target "python_egg" which is not an executable, library, or module.`. I know that I could instead use `install(FILES,...` but I don't want to copy the generated `.egg-info` anywhere, I simple want `make install` to run `pip install` if the `.egg-info` file does not yet exist. Is this possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Use `install(CODE)` or `install(SCRIPT)` for run custom code during installation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: But then how can I make sure that pip is only run when the .egg-info does not exist? I can't specify dependencies with `install(SCRIPT ...)`.

Comment: You cannot specify dependencies with any `install` command, in any form. It is assumed that `ALL` (default) target builds all files, needed for installation process. You may add `ALL` keyword to your custom target, and it will be built with guarantee prior any installation logic is started.

Comment: I didn't know that, I think I understand now.